# How lock screen in iOS for it to have only portrait orientation?

Tags: ios, orientation, rotation

I have created an app with many views and I want to have some of them only in portrait orientation.
I have coded this in .m file:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}
```

Do I need to do something else? May be in .h file?

Comment: And your solution isn't working?  If not, what happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630359/ios-6-how-do-i-restrict-some-views-to-portrait-and-allow-others-to-rotate/13194720#13194720

Answer (score 5):

Cleanest solution for me:

Go to Info.plist file and for the "Supported interface orientations", remove every value except "Portrait (bottom home button)".

Answer (score 4):

You just need to return a BOOL in that method. If you want just portrait mode, that means:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ;
}
```

If it's fine to be also Portrait Upside down (when in portrait rotate the device 180 degrees), then the method will look like:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

The last condition can be replaced with a call to `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)`, which does the same comparison
 (cf: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

LE: If this doesn't work, you can try using the follow 'hack': try to pop and push the view again (if you're using NavigationController). You can use the `popViewControllerAnimated` and `pushViewController:animated:` methods to force the controller re-query the required orientation :)
Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: It *has* to work. Please check if: a) you override the method in the right class (an UiViewController) b) the method has the right signature (name, params)

Comment: What iOS version are you using? In iOS6 things have changed a bit. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12555205/75320 and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hi, please check my latest edit, to see if it works that way.

Answer (score 2):

You have to return `YES` for the orientations you support (portrait), not simply `NO` for everything. Also make sure that in your project's target's settings you only check portrait mode as supported.

Comment: I have horizontal and portrait orientation checked in project. I want only a few screens to be only portrait. And others to be in both port. and for. orientation.

Answer (score 1):

add following methods to your viewcontroller. This will ensure only portarait mode is supported for example.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
  return NO;
 }

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
```